# Uniform convergence on compact sets preserves convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f_n:X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function where $X$ is an open convex set. If $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on compact sets, is $f$ a convex function?

I know that $f$ is a convex function on all compact subsets of $X$ but I'm not sure if it is on all $X$. So here's an attempt. Suppose, by contradiction, that there exists $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $t\in [0,1]$ such that
$$
f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) > tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2).
$$
However, there is a compact set containing $x_1,x_2$ and so the above inequality contradicts the fact that $f$ is convex on all compact sets. Hence, there cannot exist such an $x_1,x_2$ $\implies f$ is convex on $X$. Are there any issues with my proof?

Comment: You might want to use a different index variable.

Comment: Convexity is preserved under *pointwise* convergence. Are you inquiring about *strict* convexity?

Comment: Since convexity is defined in terms of the value at three points (one of these for a fixed $t$), pointwise convergence is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already remarked by max_zorn and  copper.hat,  pointwise convergence is sufficient: if $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of functions which are all convex in $X$ then also the **pointwise** limit $f$ is convex in $X$.  In fact, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, for all $x_1,x_2\in X$, and for all $t\in [0,1]$ we have that
$$
f_n(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)\leq  tf_n(x_1) + (1-t)f_n(x_2)$$
and after taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity we obtain
$$f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)\leq  tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2).$$
Notice that strict convexity is not preserved even for uniform convergence. Take for example the sequence $(x^n)_{n\geq 2}$ which are strict convex in $X=[0,1/2]$, the uniform limit in $X$ is the constant function $0$ which is not strict convex.